# image displayed in uitableview using iOS 8 is different from iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, custom-cell

I have a UITableView and in its third section, i am calling a customised cell.
In the customised cell, i am dynamically displaying images depending from the API's response. If I run my app in  iOS 8 the images are displayed with sizes and coordinates that i set. [refer to image]

[image]
But when I am running the app in iOS 7, the images displayed in the cell is different than the ones displayed in iOS 8 [refer to image]

[image]

anyone experienced this issue? how were you able to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `contentMode` of the cell's image view to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: omg..you're a life saviour..
been searching the whole day about this issue..
thanks a lot..